# How to get actual keyboard height (keyboard height minus safe area insets)

Tags: ios, swift

I tried getting the height of the keyboard to update the table contentInsets when the keyboard shows up; but the notification from `UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification` shows the frame with the safe area height. Is there a way to get the actual keyboard frame?

Code for the height of the keyboard height:

```
if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
    let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
    let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height

    print("show: \(keyboardHeight)")
    tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 18 + keyboardHeight, right: 0)
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 18 + keyboardHeight, right: 0)
}
```

But this gives the height of the following keyboard:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3uqk.jpg

What I want:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xUbW.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First you have to get Safe Area bottom height and then
>   exclude it from keyboard total height. In this way you will get only
>   keyboard height without bottom safe area.

pesudo code:

> let keyboardHeight = your keyboard height - bottomPadding

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    let bottomPadding = window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Try subtracting the height of the safe area's bottom inset when calculating the value for your constraint.

Here is a sample implementation which handles a UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame notification.

```
@objc private func keyboardWillChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let userInfo = (notification as Notification).userInfo, let value = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }
    let newHeight: CGFloat
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        newHeight = value.cgRectValue.height - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    } else {
        newHeight = value.cgRectValue.height
    }
    myConstraint.value = newHeight
}
```